# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 0 supplied

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a problem where I need to update the value of a field in a table in my sqlite3 database.

- `takenOut` is the name of the column
- `bookID` is there so it only update's that one record
- `newTakenOutEntry` is the user input, which will be put into the database by the UPDATE query
- `bookIDEntry` is the user input so the UPDATE query knows which record it is to update the takenOut field for

The code I currently have is:

```
updatetakenOut = c.execute("UPDATE bookList SET takenOut = ? WHERE bookID = ?"), (newTakenOutEntry.get(),) , (bookIDEntry.get(),)
conn.commit()
```

The error message I am getting is this:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 0 supplied.
```

I already have a comma after the `.get()` attribute for the new values so it should already be a tuple right? What I have seen online from people that have also had this error is that they didn't have the new values in a tuple. However, I am still getting an error message so I don't know what else could be the problem.

Comment: You have to supply the bindings as arguments to `execute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
updatetakenOut = c.execute("UPDATE bookList SET takenOut = ? WHERE bookID = ?", (newTakenOutEntry.get(), bookIDEntry.get()))
```